# SPDY + Express: zip file downloaded from server is corrupt

Tags: node.js, express, download, zip, spdy

Error received when opening a downloaded zip file.

[Error Opening a downloaded zip file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwxFS.png)

*NodeJS Server:* SPDY and Express using http2

I have created an api route to download a zip file. The zip file downloaded in Chrome/Firefox is corrupt, but when tested the same route in Postman with "Send and Download". I was able to get the file and was able to open the zip file

Code to generate archive file on the server side and pipe it to the response

```
const archive: archiver.Archiver = archiver('zip');

archive.on('error', error => next(new ServerError(500, error.message)));
archive.on('end', () => {
    console.log(`Total bytes: ${archive.pointer()}`);
    res.end();
});
archive.pipe(res);

strArr.forEach((str, idx) => archive.append(str, { name: `${idx}.txt` }));
archive.finalize();
```

There is a difference in the file sizes that are downloaded

[Difference in file sizes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTPG8.png)

In all these 3 requests to backend, the API returned the same number of bytes

```
Total bytes: 27137312
```